# How to encode the Chinese word using PHP?

Tags: php, encode

I need to encode the Chinese word using php for an example

> %E7%8F%AD%E7%BA%B3-bangna

to

> 班纳-bangna

Please try to give me a good solution for me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `urldecode`

```
$str = "%E7%8F%AD%E7%BA%B3-bangna";
echo urldecode($str);
```

> Output
>
> 班纳-bangna

[Demo](https://eval.in/519276)

Comment: Also `rawurldecode()` should be considered, depending on how the author wants to treat the "+" characters.